# Encoding App.Config

Tags: c#

I made application which is connecting to my sql database. I want to send this app to some users to let them obtain values from database by using SELECT command.

I want to hide credentials of my database. I searched a bit about encoding data and I found a tutorial about it.

Here is the link: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Connection-String-in-AppConfig-file.aspx

Well I done everything the same. What's more I added `System.Configuration` reference.

Right now, the only error existing is:`The name 'Configurationmanager' does not exist in the current context`. Every solution of this problem I found was related with adding `Configuration Manager` reference. As I said, I already added this.

Do you have any idea? By default, my `App.Config` file was looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
     <add name="Settings" value="---MY LOGIN AND PASSWORD---" />
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

At first I changed this (according to tutorial) like this:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings> 
     <add name="Settings" connectionString="---MY LOGIN AND PASSWORD---" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Right now App.Config is: (I changed random chars a bit)

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
        <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
                    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
                    </KeyInfo>
                    <CipherData>
                        <CipherValue>BFdcvx34Vw/TRVHRXMfDFfdmdfdksfoTC0JaLZZDY2lF/SWyr5BYS1mE3i8czp1izQ20bQC1/3pR3uLtD5yFsdfmdsfkw86S5QG1ctinXQ7gd+rrcuF1/Xws5ixbtvOPX/Itls/dMqfZcTJ9PY=</CipherValue>
                    </CipherData>
                </EncryptedKey>
            </KeyInfo>
            <CipherData>
                <CipherValue>qHGxbtVbAuNeC163xJc0zGja5LMv34GQBTFPS3fywLCF9YGr1fA+FslaNQBavz90JQbimEJaEzIIHYyyKASOBkdaHDTPDSffsdfxzLDV3gN4T2EtDWTk1zhyY7VASD34wqedNXNvn6jIMgJZAyJMlfXASddasdasfI0qGoJNj8Gq7hhEO0QBugXEVl/zTmHqWYfMDsWI5IgIvRLePhOrNrmTAFldASDasda4ewaASe8Z6nbdxASDas231MASNEUE6RK7YJ</CipherValue>
            </CipherData>
        </EncryptedData>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You should never do that. Build a web service to wrap your database, and authenticate users there.

Comment: I agree with Lex, i would do a REST webservice, where they can put the query, and get de return.

Comment: I think my skills are not good enough to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You must be sure the class System.ConfigurationManager is referenced into your code.

See:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I added `System Configuration` from Assembly and wrote: `using System.Configuration;`

Comment: For WEB you need another class instead the above: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt the connection string and put it in your app.config. The Cypher/salt needs to be hidden and should never be in the app.config. Hard-code that in your app.

A further problem is a user can open your app in notepad and see the cypher because it is plain text, so ensure you encode that as a byte array or something to make it more difficult.

Lastly use an obfuscator so they can't easily turn your app back into code.

Not perfect but if someone has the time/money they will always be able to figure it out. Need to make it hard enough that it is not worth the time/money.

Comment: Yes, i know. The thing is when I am not able to use connectionstring. I can use only "value" instead.